# Rollback in multiple service operations in Spring, jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate, rollback

I have a controller which calls three services A,B and C and these services calls their own DAO to perform insertion into the database.
The problem is if for example something goes wrong with service C, then A and B still persists in the database. I want that if anything goes wrong with the any of the service then the previous database operations performed by the other services should be able to rollback. How do I achieve this?

```
@PostMapping('/data')
public String insertData(@RequestBody String data){
   A.insert(data);
   B.insert(data);
   C.insert(data);
   return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Transaction at controller level - simple, easy to introduce - on the other hand, long lasting transactions.
2. [Saga design pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) - complicated, but deals with all the cases.

Comment: So does that mean in a saga pattern, I would have to implement something to explicitly delete the inserted data?

Comment: @inquisitive In short yes. Each component performs full operation. Revert means - for instance delete, or maybe you need to see that something was reverted? Also not always you have transactional interface, multi level transactional interface... Sounds complicated? - yes - but you can slice it into pieces, and implement each one, step by step.